# VB.NET Get directory and sub-directory from path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to get the full path minus the filename from a path in vb.net.  I'm using a textbox and a browse button to get the full path, but I want to save just the directories.

How do I get just the directories and sub-directories?

**Example file name:**

- c:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\file.aspx

**Desired result:**

- c:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\

  ```
  Protected Sub btnBackupFolderName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackupFolderName.Click

  ' Call ShowDialog.
  Dim result As DialogResult = openFD.ShowDialog()

  ' Test result.
  If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      Dim FileNameText As String = openFD.FileName.ToString()          

      Dim backupFolderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileNameText))  'this just gives me 'Desktop'
      txtBackupFolder.Text = di.ToString 'backupFolderName          
  End If

  End Sub
  ```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Get the full path of the file and then use GetDirectoryName() to retrieve the folder-path.

Comment: @R.J. Dunnill, That did it, if you would you like to make it an answer?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the full path of the file and then use GetDirectoryName() to retrieve the folder-path, like this:

```
Dim openFD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

Dim result As DialogResult = openFD.ShowDialog()
If result = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim FileNameText As String = openFD.FileName.ToString()
    ' This gets the folder-path, sans filename.
    txtBackupFolder.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName)
End If
```